# How can I get an input by the user without using the printf statement?

Tags: c, printing, printf, coding-style, scanf

That is my code above. I have to read in 10 strings input by the user but I cannot figure out how to read in the 10 strings and store them in an Array without having to print a statement saying "enter string".

The above but without the print statement. The only output of the program should be the alphabetically sorted sting

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ARRAY_LENGTH 10
#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 100

int compare_strings(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return strcmp(*(const char**)b, *(const char**)a);
}

int main() {
    char *strings[ARRAY_LENGTH];
    char input_string[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
    
    // Read in 10 strings and store them in the array
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH; i++) {
        printf("Enter string #%d: ", i+1);
        fgets(input_string, MAX_STRING_LENGTH, stdin);
        input_string[strcspn(input_string, "\n")] = '\0'; // remove newline character
        strings[i] = malloc(strlen(input_string) + 1); // allocate memory for string
        strcpy(strings[i], input_string);
    }

    // Sort the strings in reverse alphabetical order
    qsort(strings, ARRAY_LENGTH, sizeof(char*), compare_strings);

    // Print the sorted strings
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH; i++) {
        printf("%s ", strings[i]);
        free(strings[i]); // free memory for string
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correct. You will get the expected behavior by removing the `printf` line. Without that you do not print anything and that's unrelated from reading with `fgets`.

Comment: I would like to just feed in 10 words as stings into the console when I run the program without the program printing out a prompt for me to enter the values when I run the program

Comment: Then remove the `printf`, that prints the prompt: https://godbolt.org/z/rnr4P7qd9

Comment: What happened when you simply did not print anything? How did it not work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the print statement:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH; i++) {
//      printf("Enter string #%d: ", i+1);
        fgets(input_string, MAX_STRING_LENGTH, stdin);
        input_string[strcspn(input_string, "\n")] = '\0'; // remove newline character
        strings[i] = malloc(strlen(input_string) + 1); // allocate memory for string
        strcpy(strings[i], input_string);
    }
```

Aside:

1. What happens when the line exceeds `MAX_STRING_LENGTH`?
2. Do not call `strcspn()` when you need the string length. Call `strlen()` directly and check whether the size is greater than 0 and the last character read was a `'\n` before stripping it.

```
size_t len = strlen (input_string);

if (len > 0 && input_string[len - 1] == '\n') {
    input_string[--len] = '\0';
```

3. Code risks invoking undefined behaviour if `malloc()` returned `NULL`.
4. `fgets()` returns `NULL` on end-of-file or a read error.